# how to publish a yomen generator?

Tags: javascript, yo

I have forked a Yomen generator and changed it a little bit, `npm link` works great.
I don't know how to publish my generator, It's already on [Github](https://github.com/aminroosta/generator-ko2).
How can i publish this generator so it can be installed by `npm install -g generator-name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm publish` your package if you have an account in [npmjs.org](http://npmjs.org)

if you don't have an account, `npm adduser` to create one.